# SASS Mixin Arguments ignored

Tags: inheritance, sass, mixins

I'm learning SASS and building my own pattern library in order to do so, nothing fancy. I have everything working well apart form one odd issue. I have created mixin:

```
@mixin standout($background-colour: #F0F0F0, $top-margins: 5%, $bottom-margins: 0, $text-align-center: true) {
  background: $background-colour;
  margin-top: $top-margins;
  margin-bottom: $bottom-margins;
  @if $text-align-center == true {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

In my main.scss I include it:

```
.Stand-Out {
  @include standout(#CAAC27, 10%, 5%, true);
}
```

However the CSS compiled is:

```
.Stand-Out {
  background-color: #F0F0F0; }
```

I'm guessing SASS is inheriting values from elsewhere?

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue everything seems to work well. is there any other mixin with the same name maybe?

Comment: Also cannot reproduce:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/f94cc841a48833b9dc7d

Comment: I wonder if it's inheriting from another mixing? The GIT is here: https://github.com/fingerpuk/POG

Comment: I'm not able to find this mixin in your source control.

Comment: Try the Andrew branch.